# How to proxy calls from any ip to exit from a single, authorized, ips to a customer's webserver?

Tags: networking, proxy, webserver, api

I have a webserver. This server is authorized to make call to another private customer's api server

> Note: this webserver is internal to our office. Our office is behind a VPN, so webserver is accessible from extern only to vpn authorized users

For development purpose only, we need to be able to call this server from others, unauthorized ip

Some my idea is to prepare "something" to receive api call from *any* address and forward to the customer's api server, and, obviously, to reply to the right ip/client the response from the web server.

The comunication is always started from our office, the customer's api server never calls us.

How / what can I install something to allow coworkers to make api calls to my ip, to a custom address and domain of course, and then have every request trasparently routed to the customer's api ?

example:

Ugo from home has ip 3.3.3.3 and need to make an api call to 10.10.10.10
Stefano needs from ip 4.4.4.4 to call 10.10.10.10

but only 1.1.1.1 is authorized to call 10.10.10.10.

we want to install something on 1.1.1.1 so that every ip calling ip will forward a call to 10.10.10.10.

does something like this exists?
we can do it on linux/windows/everyting else

sorry for confused question, i am a programmer, not a network engineers or any also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much exactly what a 'reverse proxy' does. You might already have a reverse proxy as part of your web server setup, or you could configure Nginx or Apache to do the job – it doesn't sound like any special configuration would be needed, just the most basic 'ProxyPass'.

However, the IP restriction that you currently have is there for a reason – you might even have contractual obligations to prevent outsiders from abusing the access that you've been granted. So IMHO you *should* add some authentication to the proxy setup (such as Apache's 'AuthType Basic' or at least 'Require ip <stefano_ip>'), otherwise someone might discover the open API endpoint and the other private customer might revoke your access altogether.

Alternatively, a 'forward' HTTP or SOCKS proxy could also be used (aka the "regular" kind of proxy, e.g. Squid or again Apache), though then it is necessary for callers to explicitly use that proxy, which might be annoying to do in some HTTP APIs (whereas a reverse proxy just looks like a regular web server).

If the developers are allowed to SSH directly into the web server, they could configure a tunnel in their SSH client (e.g. the `ssh -D` option), allowing them to connect to anything they want using the server's IP address.

(Finally, to generalize it even further, a VPN could be set up for developers to use... but it's probably not a good idea to do that on a prod web server – I'm only mentioning it as the most generic method of "borrowing another IP address".)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. About ip restrictions, it's in place an ip block, based on ip of our office. but we can access proxy in our office only using a vpn, so we are tutelated